# How create universal framework for iOS without slicing for AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

How to create framework like Firebase which I can run on the devices and simulator and I can publish my app without slicing it?

I read a lot of information about frameworks.

I found article how to make universal fat framework which will works on the simulation and device.

But all instructions has comments that those solution doesn't work fine for uploading to App Store, like: "There is only one issue with fat architectures. They contain slices for the simulator as well. If you want to submit your app to the app store, you have to cut off the simulator related codebase from the framework."

And all articles is offering add specific scrip to slicing frameworks.

But how does it works for the most popular framework? 
Crashlytics, Firebase and etc works on the simulators and devices and you can publish your app with this frameworks without additional scripts.